# Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements

Tags: floats, sectioning, numbering, counters

Some document elements (e.g., figures in the `book` class) are numbered per chapter (figure 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, ...). How can I achieve continuous numbering (figure 1, 2, 3, ...)?

And vice versa: Some document elements (e.g., figures in the `article` class) are numbered continuously. How can I achieve per-section numbering?

```
\documentclass{book}% for "vice versa" variant, replace `book` with `article`

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}% for "vice versa" variant, replace `\chapter` with `\section`

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Bonus question: Is it possible to adjust the numbering of the sectioning headings themselves? Can I, e.g., switch from per-chapter to continuous numbering of sections in the `book` class?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Changing the numbering of (e.g.) figures involves two modifications:

1. Redefining whether or not the `figure` counter will be reset whenever the chapter/section counter is incremented;
2. Redefining the "appearance" of the `figure` counter (`\thefigure`), i.e., removing (or adding) the chapter/section prefix.

### Standard solution: `\counterwithout`

The standard solution – which deals with modifications 1 and 2 mentioned above – is to use the `\counterwithout` and `\counterwithin` commands.

<sub>Since October 2018 the commands are in the LaTeX kernel; for earlier releases one needs [`\usepackage{chngcntr}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr)</sub>

The following example shows how to achieve continuous figure numbering in the `book` class:

```
\documentclass{book}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Conversely, here's how to achieve per-section figure numbering in the `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It works the same way for (e.g.) tables, custom-defined floats, equations, and footnotes. (Note that in many document classes featuring the `\chapter` command, footnotes are numbered per chapter even though the `footnote` counter does not show the chapter prefix.) The commands may also be used for theorem environments; it is easier, though, to specify the numbering of a new theorem environment when defining it:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}% Continuous numbering
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]% Per-section numbering
```

You may also customize the numbering of the sectioning headings themselves. To, say, accomplish continuous numbering of sections in the `book` class (by default, those are numbered per chapter), but per-part numbering of chapters (which are by default numbered continuously), your preamble should contain

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
```

To influence the resetting of counters *without* changing their appearance, use the starred macro versions `\counterwithout*` and `\counterwithin*`. E.g., for per-section numbering of figures in the `article` class – but without attaching a section prefix to `\thefigure` –, add the following to your preamble:

```
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
```

It is also possible to redefine a counter's resetting and appearance any number of times in the document body. Note that `\counterwithout`, `\counterwithin` and their variants won't affect the counter's current value; to change the latter, use `\setcounter{<counter>}{<new value>}`.

### AMSmath solution

The [AMS classes](http://ctan.org/pkg/amscls) and the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package feature the `\numberwithin` macro which matches `\counterwithin`. However, there is no AMS equivalent to `\counterwithout`. Usage example: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`. See the [full example by cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54242/213). If you use math, you may prefer loading `amsmath` anyway and using `\numberwithin`.

### Other solutions

The [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package features the key–value options `figurewithin` and `tablewithin` which allow to change the numbering of (surprise) figures and tables. Permitted option values are `chapter`, `section`, and `none`. (For the first code example above, this translates into `\usepackage[figurewithin=none]{caption}`.)

The [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package uses `\AtBeginDocument` to define the `lstlisting` counter of the environment of the same name. To turn off the environment's per-chapter numbering for classes that feature `\chapter`, issue `\lstset{numberbychapter=false}` in the document preamble. To enable per-section numbering for classes without `\chapter`, add the following to your preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}
```

Comment: How would I use the amsmath's numberwithin to achieve this numbering style on all defined theoremstyles? Sorry if this is answered above and I am just missing it.

Comment: @BBischof When you say `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]`, the `thm` environment will be numbered in the form <chapter>.<theorem>; a following `\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}` will use the same counter for lemmas as for theorems.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your comment. It seems helpful, but I am a little confused. Could you be a bit more verbose? :/

Comment: Can you add a package-free option here as well? Something using `\@addtoreset`?

Comment: I believe since the 2018 release the macro  \counterwithout` is integrated in the LaTeX kernel. It might be worth updating the answer.

Comment: If you are using the `memoir` class with the `\mainmatter` command make sure to put the `\counterwithout` command after the `\mainmatter` command, see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369854/memoir-chapter-based-figure-numbering

Answer (score 16):

Patryk's answer works perfectly. But you need to reset the counter of tables, figures, equations, etc. manually every time you want to start your object labels at "1" again. So it would be more suitable for e.g. a paper with some appendices than for a book with many chapters.

The `\renewcommand` line you only have to set once.

The advantage is that it is super simple and flexible.

Like this:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

To create "Figure A1.1"

You could also do

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Appendix~\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

to obtain "Figure Appendix 1.1" (if you would feel the urge).

Or

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{figure}}
```

to obtain "Figure A1.1.1" for Figure 1 in subsection 1 of section A1.

Answer (score 7):

Strangely enough, no one mentioned the package `remreset` and its `\@removefromreset` macro or the LaTeX - core macro `\@addtoreset` yet.

See for another version with `xassoccnt` at the bottom of this post.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{figure}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\section{A section that causes resetting of figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Third figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Using `xassoccnt` there is `\RemoveFromReset` and `\AddToReset` (without using `\makeatletter...\makeatother`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\RemoveFromReset{figure}{chapter}
\AddToReset{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\section{A section that causes resetting of figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Third figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Please note that there is `\RemoveFromFullReset` as well, which removes the counter and its own reset list from the driver reset list.

**Update** Starting with version 1.3 of `xassoccnt`, `\AddToReset`, `\RemoveFromReset` support comma - separated list of counters to be added or removed from the driver counter reset list. Current version is `1.5`, as of 2017/10/20.

Answer (score 3):

You can also redefine `thefigure` command

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
```

and in `article` class

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Comment: Only redefining `\thefigure` does nothing with regard to counter resetting and therefore may result, e.g., in figures in different chapters featuring the same name "Figure 1".

Comment: @Patryk, That worked awesome for me. Just as I wanted, I have Chapters in romans and I when I type an equation, it shows like (I.1), (Equation 1 for chapter I), when I did your command, I changed "\thefigure" for "\theequation" and "figure" for "equation" (in your first quote), and I got it just like I wanted, i.e. (1.1) (equation 1 for chapter I), without changing my chapters to arabic numbers. Thanks :)