# labeling tables per chapter both in the body and in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, numbering, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

How can I label the tables per chapter in document class `report` rather than the continuous numbering in both the body and in the list of tables. I am writing a thesis. I have tried a few tricks but they did not work. I have tried:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

But it displyed `'chngcntr.sty' not found`.

I also want to write 'chapter one' instead of 'chapter 1' using:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}} % for lowercase one, two, three, ...
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

But it displayed `'fmtcount.sty' not found`.

Are there other things I can do or where did I get it wrong? Please assist.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: This site works best if you ask one question at a time. I'd suggest you remove of your question and post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

- You could install the `chngcntr` package either with your TeX distribution package manager or manually from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr).
- Or use `amsmath` instead, which is installed for sure, it provides also a command for numbering within chapters or sections etc.:

  ```
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \numberwithin{table}{chapter}
  ```

I recommend to adjust also the numbering of other environments such as tables or equations, to get a consistent numbering style in your document.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `xxx.sty not found` indicates that the package you're trying to load is not installed on your system. Depending on whether you're using MiKTeX or TeX Live, you'll find help on installing packages at http://docs.miktex.org/faq/packages.html or at http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#install__option_____pkg___.

Answer (score 1):

Tables *are* numbered after chapters in `report`. Try e.g. the following

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1 title}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption for table in chapter 1}
\end{table}

\chapter{Chapter 2 title}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption for first table in chapter 2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption for second table in chapter 2}
\end{table}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

which labels the first table as 1.1, the second as 2.1 and the third as 2.2.