# Numbering Sections with Sequential Integers

Tags: sectioning, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

I am using the `book` document class and have parts, chapters, sections and subsections. Currently, the following default numbering scheme is being used and produces the following:

```
Part I
--Chapter 1
----Section 1.1
------ Subsection 1.1.1
----Section 1.2
------ Subsection 1.2.1
--Chapter 2
----Section 2.1
----Section 2.2
--etc.
```

What I would like, however, is to number the sections with sequential integers, like so:

```
Part I
--Chapter 1
----Section 1
------Subsection 1.1
----Section 2
------Subsection 2.1 
--Chapter 2
----Section 3
----Section 4
--etc.
```

Basically, I just want the section counter to be integral and be reused while the other numbering remains (relatively) this same. What must I do to effect this scheme?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

from the [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr):

[image: Section number continuous across chapters]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\section{A section}
\end{document}​
```

`\counterwithout{<cntrA>}{<cntrB>}` removes the resetting of `<cntrA>` when `<cntrB>` is incremented. In `book` and `report`, this is the default.