# Revert (reverse) \numberwithin effect

Tags: numbering, counters

How can I revert the action of `\numberwithin{mycounter}{section}` so that `mycounter` does not reset with a new section?

**Example:** (This is not exactly my case but this is easy to understand.) I would like to have `equation` numbered within a section in the first part of the document, so I use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`. But in the next part to number it directly. Like

```
Section 1
  equation (1.1)
  equation (1.2)
Section 2
  equation (2.1)
  equation (2.2)
  equation (2.3)
\SomeCommandToPutHere{equation}
Section 3
  equation (1)
  equation (2)
  equation (3)
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package `chngcntr` does exactly that:

```
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\counterwithout{equation}{section}
```

Comment: Thanks, master! Just a note, the macro `\counterwithout` kills the effect of both `\numberwithin` and  `\counterwithin`, which is terrific!

Comment: Either use `\numberwithin` or `\counterwithin`, not both.

Comment: ... and what should I do if some package uses `\numberwithin` itself without giving me a chance to prevent it? And to the case, I was thinking about putting `\let\numberwithin\counterwithin` after loading both `amsmath` and `chngcntr`.

Comment: The difference between `\numberwithin` and `\counterwithin` is that the former does a global redefinition, it shouldn't be a problem if `\numberwithin` is used only in the preamble.