# table numbering style

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices

The tables in my document are labeled 1...N; I like this format.  I also have a table which belongs to the appendix of my paper that I would labeled A1 or A.1 .  Is there a way to change the numbering style for just that one specific table? I use LyX for my editor.

Comment: Are you using the `\appendix` command?

Comment: Please tell us more about the numbering style you'd like to see implemented for one specific table.

Comment: @Sigur: yes, i use `\appendix`

Comment: @Mico: I would the table in the appendix labeled `A1` or `A.1`

Comment: @Alex, in fact, that command only change the section counters. Which class are you using?

Comment: @Sigur: correct, it changes the section counter. the goal is to make my labeling of the appendix table have a different format than the rest of the paper

Comment: @Alex, see my suggested answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\numberwithin` from the `amsmath` package.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Normal}
\begin{table}   
\caption{Normal Table}
\end{table}

\appendix
\numberwithin{table}{section}

\section{First Appendix}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table in Appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**:
Having seen [This note on numberwithin outside the preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42297/revert-reverse-numberwithin-effect#comment86261_42299) (and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28147/changing-number-within-numberwithin-causes-malfunction-but-no-compile-error#comment55391_28148)) here's an alternative version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\section{Normal}
\begin{table}   
\caption{Normal Table}
\end{table}

\appendix
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\section{First Appendix}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table in Appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Easier. Nice! +1

Answer (score 2):

From `article.cls` we found the definition of `\appendix` command:

```
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}
```

So the counters `section` and `subsection` are reseted. Also the command `\thesection` is defined to print the counter `section` using alphanumeric.

My suggestion is to use

```
\appendix
\makeatletter
\setcounter{table}{0}
\gdef\thetable{\@Alph\c@section.\@arabic\c@table}
\makeatother
```

to reset the `table` counter and define the command `\thetable` to print the `section` counter using alphanumeric followed by the `table` counter in arabic.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it yourself very easily.  Figures, tables, equations are all taken care of here.  And you have `\appendix` for multiple appendices, or `\appendix*` for a single appendix.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{boxhandler}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\appendix{\@ifstar{\loneappendix}{\anappendix}}

\newcounter{appndx}
\setcounter{appndx}{0}

\newcommand \loneappendix [1]{
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appndx}
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{appndx}}
  \renewcommand\thesection {\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}.}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesubsection {\Alph{appndx}.\@arabic\c@subsection}
  \setcounter{paragraph}{0}
  \setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}\arabic{table}}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname. #1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \theappendix\appendixtitle
}

\newcommand \anappendix[1]{
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appndx}
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{appndx}}
  \renewcommand\thesection {\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}.}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesubsection {\Alph{appndx}.\@arabic\c@subsection}
  \setcounter{paragraph}{0}
  \setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}. #1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \theappendix\appendixtitle
}
\newcommand\theappendix[1]{
  \section*{#1}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\bxtable[ht]{Caption}{\rule{2in}{1in}}
\section{Second Section}
Text
\begin{equation}
 y =x^2 
\end{equation}

\appendix{First of Many Appendices}
Let's see if tables are renumbered

\bxtable[ht]{Caption}{\rule{2in}{1in}}
\bxfigure[ht]{Caption}{\rule{2in}{1in}}

\begin{equation}
 y =x^2 
\end{equation}

or I could have called one single appendix:

\appendix*{My Lone Appendix}

The rest follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]