# listings caption number

Tags: listings, numbering

I'm using the `listings` package with this `\begin` command:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
   language=Python,
   caption={Simple Python Program},
]
```

This yields a nice code listing with a caption like "Listing 1 Simple Python Program".
Is there a way to change the caption and have something like "Listing 1-1 Simple Python Program" in which the 1-1 is the combination of the section number and the subsection number?

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Answer (score 6):

Listings are printed with the counter `lstlisting`. You can modify the way it prints and prepend the section number `\thesection` using

```
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection-\arabic{lstlisting}}
```

Here's a minimal example showing the same listing using two different numbering styles. Add the above code to your document preamble *after* loading the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\begin{lstlisting}[
   language=Python,
   caption={Simple Python Program}
]
print "Hello, World!"
\end{lstlisting}

\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection-\arabic{lstlisting}}

\begin{lstlisting}[
   language=Python,
   caption={Simple Python Program}
]
print "Hello, World!"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

If all your listings use `language=Python`, you can perform a global setting via

```
\lstset{language=Python}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use something like this in your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}
```

This would resemble the same behaviour as:

```
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}
```

But I think the first variant is much cleaner and more flexible.
You could specify `\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsection}}` just as well.

Or `\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter}}` if you like.

I hope this helps.