# Customizing figure counters

Tags: floats, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

I'm using the `book` class. I want to count my figures as "Figure 1.", "Figure 2.", etc. throughout my document. The numbers should *not* reset when new chapter, section or subsection begins. The counter should just keep on going until the very end of the document. How do I accomplish this? (I'm also using the `caption` package to customize my captions, by the way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are already using the `caption` package, simply add

```
\captionsetup{figurewithin=none}
```

to the preamble, after loading the package.