# Changing Table Numbering Scheme to Include Section Number

Tags: tables, numbering

When I create a table and use \caption, Latex automatically adds "Table 1.1" or something similarly numbered. I'm using the book format, and want the caption numbering to be of the form "Table x.y.z", where x is the chapter number, y is the section number, and z is the table number within x.y. For example, the second table in section 4 in chapter 2 should say "Table 2.4.2".
How do I make Latex change the numbering of the tables?

Comment: You can use the `chngcntr` package, plus `\counterwithin{table}{section}`.  See this question [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/2693) for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although your question is closely related to the following question, the numbering scheme you want is different.

- [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/2693)

The general solution is the same, however:

Use the `chngcntr` package to determine which counters depend on which.  In your case, you want the `table` counter to depend on the `section` counter, so you add

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

Comment: bit of a shame that Peter invented a new name for this and did not use the amsmath name that is around for ages

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I guess if he used the same name, the package might clash with amsmath. This way there's no conflict (even though it wouldn't be needed). I don't know if that was the reasoning.

Comment: I was thinking about that but in this particular case it doesn't really make much sense as he could have just "provided" the definition ... well it is the way it is by now.

Answer (score 9):

For this two things are needed:

1. the `table` counter need resetting whenever the `section` counter is
   stepped
2. the command to display the counter value should show the combination of chapter, section and table.

You achieve the first by placing

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\makeatother
```

into the preamble of your document. The second step is done through

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
```

where `\thesection` is the "display number" of the current section which in book is equiv to `\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}`.

#### When using amsmath

If you use the `amsmath` package the solution is even simpler as this packages offers a declaration that combines the above steps:

```
\numberwithin{table}{section}
```

Comment: I like this solution over using another package because it allows you to modify the appearance, for example if someone wanted to us a dash or other separator, `\thesection-\arabic{section}`

Comment: this solution seems to destroy the ``\listoftables`` as there are the numbers now written in the caption of the table