# How to get global equation numbers in scrrprt?

Tags: equations, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

When I insert an equation in whatever environment I like in my `scrrprt` document I get a numbering like (1.1). But I have very few numbered equations in my document so I'd like to get a numbering like (1). How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [chngcntr](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr/) package.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a chapter}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\chapter{another chapter}
\begin{equation}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this resets the counter with every chapter and this is not desirable.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina --- indeed. I should have checked more carefully! I've fixed it now.

Comment: @IanThompson: While this answers the question, there's already a very detailed answer at the duplicate question that's been linked to. In general, it's preferable to vote to close in a case like this, instead of duplicating information. That will make it easier to keep information up to date.

Comment: @Jake --- I'm aware of that, but I didn't see the comment pointing to the duplicate. I was in the process of editing my answer.