# Section numbering of equations without \section

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering

I want to use the section numbering in the equations like (1.1), (1.2), ... (3.2). But I don't want to use `\section` command. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you expand your question adding some more detail? If there's no section, what should the first number mean?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54241/change-the-type-of-equation-numbering-in-document-class-article?rq=1)  what you are looking for?

Comment: To the close-voters: I do not completely understand what makes you sure that this question is a duplicate of the other one. It might be one, but IMHO there's currently not enough information to decide that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remarks

You might want to use the `\numberwithin` directive, like

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{equation}
    \hat{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^n}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(t) \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: ex1]