# \ref{} refers to the corresponding section, not the specific environment

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

In my Latex, I am using
`\usepackage{chngcntr}  \counterwithin{equation}{section}`
to keep track of my equation environments sectionwise but when I am labeling and then referring to the labels, it refers to the corresponding section, not the environment I wish to refer to.

Can anybody kindly mention what am I missing here, to refer to any environment specificly and independently of its section or subsection or whatever?!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It will be real hard to help you out without an example of how you're using label and ref.

Comment: You are probably setting `\label` in the wrong place.

Comment: Please take my code as an example and modify it according to your use case. Then you can ask a follow-up question (or modify this one) in which you show us your code and explain your problem. Otherwise you are wasting everybody's time including your own time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps.

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54241
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % <-- Important

\begin{document}

\section{Here is a section}
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=x^2+\sin(x)
    \label{eq:lala}
\end{equation}

See \eqref{eq:lala}. Equation \ref{eq:lala} is pretty nice.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` and `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` do *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: Oh thanks. I wasn't aware of that, but one more thing, if I use `\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}` and refer the axiom environmnt, that refers to the corresponding section, not the specific environment I want? This is alright for equation or align, only `\newtheorem{}` gives trouble! Why so, and what's possible remedy?

Comment: @prikarsartam: You need to show your code for us to help. The location of `\label` is important.

Comment: @egreg My "answer" is more an attempt to give the OP an mwe. The question is very unclear to me. I was in a hurry and just thought "better than nothing"