# How do I use simple integer numbering for subsections?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to use a list of `\subsection` elements numbered "1", "2", "3", "4"... but by default they're numbered "0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "0.4".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `\section*` doesn't allow for a resetting of the `subsection` counter. For ease-of-use, you could redefine `\section` to *always* be `\section*` using the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\stepcounter{section}\oldsection*}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
%\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Last subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Last subsection}
\section{Last section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\subsection{Last subsection}
\end{document}
```

If your `subsection` should be numbered continuously (without resetting after every section), then all you need to do is remove `\stepcounter{section}` from the redefinition of `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\oldsection*}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
%\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
\begin{document}
```

The [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) provides a similar mechanism for removing counter dependencies. For more on this kind of manipulation, see [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764).

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 11):

Add to the preamble

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
```