# Table references showing up with section number instead of table number

Tags: floats, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

My table references are showing up with the section number in them. I'd like all tables in the article to be numbered sequentially with out regard to section.

Here's my header. Thanks!

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for fancy tables
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} % for llbracket, rrbracket
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for llbracket, rrbracket
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
```

Update:

I'm already in article class. The tables themselves show up numbered simply and correctly, e.g. Table 3. References to the tables, though, seem to actually give only the section name the tables are in. E.g. a table from section 3.1 shows up as "3.1" when I use \ref{tablename}.

Tried this, no effect:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)

Comment: The easiest approach would be to use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package with `\counterwithout{table}{section}`.

Comment: *Always* put `\label` *after* `\caption` inside your `table`. I'm guessing this is not the case in your document, correct?

Comment: You are too good. That was it. Would you add that as the answer so I can accept? Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Always put `\label` after `\caption` inside your `table`, otherwise you may receive unwanted references. The reason for this is that `\label` captures the most recently updated and counter (set using `\refstepcounter`). This only occurs *after* a call to `\caption`.

Comment: Highly underrated answer.