# LyX Question on Table Numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, lyx

How can you change table numbers in LyX. I want to get tables numbered within section (Table 1.1, 1.2 etc.). For some reason `\numberwithin{table}{section}` is not working.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Answer (score 1):

`\numberwithin{<slave>}{<master>}` is a macro defined by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). So, in order to use it, you need to add the following to your LaTeX Preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
```

Similar functionality is provided by [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr), via macros like `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout`. The latter package provides the means to removing any counter bindings, which `amsmath` does not offer.