# figures numbering to 3 levels rather than 2

Tags: floats, numbering

For some reason my current 'report' has started numbering figures to 3 levels... so if something is within chapter 1, but section 1.3, the figure gets numbered 1.3.1...

This isn't what I want... it's too much granularity for me. I just figures numbered in order within the chapter... so 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 as they appear, regardless of the section within the chapter in which they appear.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Comment: Use `\numberwithout{figure}{section}\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}`. This should remove the `figure` counter slaving to the  `section` counter and re-insert it to slave after `chapter`.

Comment: numberwithout...? does that exist? I just googled it and only numberwithin came up. It also gives me an error in latex..."undefined control sequence". Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're also using the `amsmath` package, you could issue the command

```
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
```

to reset the numbering system for `figure`-type floats. Try issuing this command toward the end of the preamble, i.e., after any packages that may affect the numbering system for figures are loaded.

Do check, though, if you're already loading some package or issuing some commands that forces figures to be numbered at the section level rather than at the chapter level. If so, you might try disabling (e.g., by commenting out) the unwanted instructions.

Comment: Yeah I can't see anything I'm issuing that would make it do that. I do have asmath package installed though. I tried adding your suggestion to my preamble and I got an erro saying "tex capacity exceeded"...?

Comment: Thanks... sadly not making any difference at all...

Comment: @RobD - My bad, it should have been `\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}` (as lockstep has already pointed out).