# Setting parent of a counter and removing counter from caption

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

I guess, I have two questions.

My very concrete problem is that I want `\caption{xyz}` to not print a table counter within a table. By now it prints “Table 0.1: xyz“. How would I remove that?

But maybe I want to keep the “1”. How can I remove the section parent from the table counter such that my output becomes “Table 1:”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tables really are numbered by *section*, the following should help:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
```

See also [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume).

To remove "Table N: " from "Table N: xyz", load the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package in the preamble and use the starred macro version `\caption*{xyz}` inside `table` environments.