# Section Counter: 0.1 steps, starting at 1.1

Tags: sectioning, numbering, fontsize

I'm using `\part*` and `\section` in order to formate my file.

The problem is now, that `\section` just countrs from 1 to *n*. But what I actually need is the sections counting from 1.1 to 1.*n*, and then, after the second `\part` start over as 2.1 to 2.*m*.

I use `\part` and `\section` instead of `\section` and `\subsection` because of the fontsize.
If there is a possibility to have `\section` displayed as large as `\part`, and `\subsection` as large as `\section`, this would also be a way to solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume (especially the bonus question).

Comment: Hmmm, so the higher sectional unit (\part in your example) should be unnumbered but the following unit (\section) should receive a counter fron the higher one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility would be to redefine `\thesection` to include the `part` counter; something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{section}{part}

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part One}
\section{Test Section}
\section{Test Section}
\part{Test Part Two}
\section{Test Section}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

To get the `part` counter in arabic you can say

```
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
```

[image]

Another option would be to change the sectional unit formatting and use `\section`, `\subsection` instead of `\part`, `\section`, and this can be done, for example, with the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Your second solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Is it possible (of course it is, but how?) to add margins at the bottom of the (sub)sections?

Comment: @Marco7757 sure it's possible, but I quite don't understand what you want. Can you please describe in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: How would this be done for subsubsections counting from 1.1.1?