# Theorem environment numbered according to subsection

Tags: numbering, theorems

I was wondering if there was a way to modify the `theorem` environment so that it interacted with sections/subsections as follows:

```
\section{}
\subsection{}
\begin{ex} Whatever
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}Whatever
\end{ex}



\subsection{}

\begin{ex} Whatever

\end{ex}
```

Would output something like

```
1
1.1

Exercise 1.1.1


Exercise 1.1.2



1.2

Exercise 1.2.1
```

Where `\begin{ex}` is just an environment for an "exercise".

Comment: Sounds very doable :) could you turn your snippet into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) :)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built-in feature for theorem numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % not necessary

\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{}

\subsection{}

\begin{ex}
Whatever
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Whatever
\end{ex}

\subsection{}

\begin{ex}
Whatever
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a standard feature, not only of `amsthm`.

Comment: @egreg And there exists `\newtheorem` without `amsthm`?

Comment: Yes, of course; `amsthm` and the similar `ntheorem` just add to the kernel functionality.