# Continuous numbering of custom float with caption package

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

I defined a custom environment that allows me to define mathematical problem statements and puts them in a box. Since I have quite a few of them in my report, I decided to properly caption them, which also allows me to refer back to the problems with `cleveref`.

Here is my code [1]:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\definecolor{problemgray}{gray}{0.9}

\DeclareCaptionType{problem}[Problem][List of Problems]
\crefname{problem}{Problem}{Problems}
\Crefname{problem}{Problem}{Problems}

\newsavebox{\tmpbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{problembox}{mo}{%
    \noindent%
    \begin{lrbox}{\tmpbox}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}%
            \par\noindent%
        }{%
        \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
    \begin{center}%
        \captionof{problem}{#1}%
        \vspace{0.25em}%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.5em}
        \colorbox{problemgray}{\usebox{\tmpbox}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{
            %
        }{
            \label{#2}%
        }
    \end{center}
}
```

The format is thus: `\begin{problembox}{<problem caption>}[<optional label>]`.

In this way, the problems are currently numbered per chapter, e.g. Problem 2.1, Problem 2.2, etc. However, most of my problems build upon each other.

Thus my question,
**How can I get `caption` to continuously number custom floats rather than per chapter?**

[1] Note that I lied: The boxes are actually not floats, but I could make them floats the way I set them up. I just wanted to have a captioned but fixed environment.

*Bonus question:* How can I allow page breaks within a problem using my code?

Comment: Instead of using a lrbox use the package `framed`.

Comment: I do not see that this is a duplicate because http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume is a question about changing *existing* counters while in this case the question is "How to define the "problem" counter is a way I want". Defining it wrongly first, and correct it afterwards with the help of an additional package do not look very straight-ahead to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that the linked answered your main question.

1. Your main question can be answered with the possibilities of the package `caption`. The command `\DeclareCaptionType` has an optional argument where you can specify the behaviour of the number. In your case the option `within=none` is needed:

   ```
   \DeclareCaptionType[within=none]{problem}[Problem][List of Problems]
   ```
2. If you use a `lrbox` you can split across pages without special handling. For your case you can use the package `framed`. The example below demonstrate it.
3. You are using `xparse`. To test if a value for an optional argument is given you can use `\IfNoValue(TF)`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\DeclareCaptionType[within=none]{problem}[Problem][List of Problems]
\crefname{problem}{Problem}{Problems}
\Crefname{problem}{Problem}{Problems}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{problembox}{mo}{%
    \begin{trivlist}\item\relax%
        \captionof{problem}{#1}%
         \IfNoValueF { #2 } { \label{#2} }%
         \vspace{0.25em}%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.5em}
        \begin{shaded}
        }{%
        \end{shaded}
    \end{trivlist}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{problembox}{caption}
\lipsum
\end{problembox}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum by Axel Sommerfeldt**

When `\DeclareCaptionType` was integrated within the `caption` package people were complaining that they need to load the `caption` package to use that functionality. Therefore I outsourced it into the newborn `newfloat` package, and have removed the documentation of `\DeclareCaptionType` in the `caption` package documentation since people were complaining about the length of the `caption` documentation anyway. (I see that this wasn't the best idea so I will re-add a short reference to the `newfloat` package in the next version.) So for up-to-date documentation, please take a look at the `newfloat` package documentation, command `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`. (In fact the `caption` package still offers `\DeclareCaptionType` to be compatible to existing documents, but simply use `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` of the `newfloat` package internally. This will be done in future versions, too, so using `\DeclareCaptionType` is still fine.)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for not finding the other question.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again! But is it possible to restrict the width of the shaded box to, say, `0.9\textwidth` and centering it on the page?

Comment: @Ingo: Therefor you should use packages like mdframed or tcolorbox.

Comment: Why using the `chngcntr` package if using `\DeclareCaptionType` with option `within=none` would be sufficient?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Because it's in the `newfloat` package. `:-)`

Comment: Axel, can you provide another answer?

Comment: @Ingo No, because this question is closed.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: I changed my answer to a CW and you can edit this one.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I didn't see the code before I asked. THanks

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks. I just added an addendum about the documentation of `\DeclareCaptionType`, however I see that the current situation is some kind of confusing. (I'll try to make it better in the next version of the doc.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Thanks. Normally I type `texdoc caption` and everything is documented. This time I had to look in `caption3.sty` to see what happens.

Comment: This has been a productive post after all. Thanks everyone.