# Continuous numbering of figures and tables changes not working

Tags: floats, numbering, memoir

I'm aware of the topic: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume) and I tried use the options given, but none worked for me.
I'm using `memoir`class.
What I'm doing wrong?

I tried:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Figure remains 1.1.

So, I tried `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` since `memoir` supports this command.
Figure remains 1.1.

So I tried:

```
\usepackage[figurewithin=none]{caption}
```

Figure remains 1.1.

---

@jon This is my "style file", named folhadeestilos.txt:

```
% ---
% Pacotes
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

% ---
% Margens
% ---
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setheaderspaces{*}{1cm}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

% ---
% Fonte Arial
% ---
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{microtype}

% ---
% Customização da numeração de páginas e das seções
% ---
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{%
    \centering\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}\afterchaptertitle}

\renewcommand{\printloftitle}[1]{%
    \centering\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\afterloftitle}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}\afterchaptertitle}

\renewcommand{\printlottitle}[1]{%
    \centering\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\afterlottitle}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}\afterchaptertitle}

\chapterstyle{tandh}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{simple}
\setlength\beforechapskip{-\baselineskip}

\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
    \large\bfseries \thechapter\space}

\setsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referências Bibliográficas}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter{\bibname}}}

% ---
% Legendas e numeração de figuras e tabelas
% ---
\usepackage[center,small,bf]{caption}

% ---
% Ambiente matemático em sans serif
% ---
\everymath{\mathsf{\xdef\mysf{\mathgroup\the\mathgroup\relax}}\mysf}

% ---
% Hyperref
% ---
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

And this is my simplified main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\input{folhadeestilos.tex}

\begin{document}

...

\pagestyle{simple}
\input{mem.tex}

\end{document}
```

Where mem.tex contains the `\begin{figure}` enviroment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (revised, to take into account the new file structure):

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}% <--- used to create the two other files 'on the fly' (it makes the example self-contained)

\begin{filecontents}{folhadeestilos.sty}
 \usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mem.tex}
 \begin{table}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
     a & b \\
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{table one}
 \end{table}

 \begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
    \caption{caption one}
 \end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{folhadeestilos}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\input{mem.tex}

\section{two}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table two}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \caption{caption two}
\end{figure}

\chapter{three}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table three}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \caption{caption three}
\end{figure}

\section{four}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table four}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \caption{caption four}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you are using `memoir`'s `\<front|main|back>matter` commands, you will need to renew some definitions in order to make `\counterwithout` work as expected.

Thus, you can add to your preamble in this case (where all figures and tables are in the 'mainmatter' section):

```
\makeatletter 
 \renewcommand\@memmain@floats{%
   \counterwithout{figure}{chapter} 
   \counterwithout{table}{chapter}}             
\makeatother
```

(This could do in your personal `.sty` file, e.g.; but in that case, you don't need the two `\makeat*` commands.)

Less elegantly, you can simply move the `\counter*` commands to after the `\mainmatter` declaration.

Comment: I tried your code in a separated archive and worked too. I'm doing a thesis and I have all packages "charged" in a separated .tex and I call it `\input{archive.tex}` inside of my main .tex file, called thesis. But the archives with the tables and figures are too in separated files and as well I call them by `\input` command inside of thesis.tex. Could be this my error?

Comment: I hate myself. Why so dumb? Your example worked. I'll look my files  more carefully and see what I'm making wrong. Thank you for your time and help @jon.

Comment: @AnaNascimento -- We've all been there, never fear!  I can't even count the number of times a trivial non-problem held me up for far too long....

Comment: I figured out the problem! I was using a `\mainmatter` command. Once I put it off, the figures and tables are correctly numbered. So now I have a different problem. I was using this command because the first page of the thesis cannot be counted in numbering page sequencet. There are another way to do that without using `\mainmatter` @jon?

Comment: Perfect, @jon!!! Thank you very very very much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is now better explained in the manual for memoir 3.7. As mentioned above `\mainmatter` resets the numbering. Here is what is now mentioned in the manual as a solution:

```
\makeatletter
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand\@memfront@floats{}
\renewcommand\@memmain@floats{}
\newcommand\@memback@floats{}
\makeatletter
```

the three `\...@floats` macros are issued by `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` and resets in verious ways.