# Problem in numbering of figures and tables for thesis

Tags: numbering

I encountered problems with numbering of figure and table in thesis where it should be appeared Figure/Table 1.1,1.2...2.1 . 
I have tried to solve this problem form this post [[here]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116799/continuous-numbering-of-figures-and-tables-changes-not-working) as well as [[here]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume). I have make changes according to the following suggestion from this link such as:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

or

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Yet. there is no changes in the numbering... Below is my MWE

```
\documentclass{uumthesis}
\usepackage[nosectionbib,natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\st@rtbibchapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}}{\addxcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
{\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\bibname}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

......

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{myref}
\end{document}
```

here is the example from the figures
[image: This suppose to be figure 1.1]

[image: This suppose to be figure 1.4]

as you can see, numbering of figure is not according to section

Comment: I cannot test your example because the `uumthesis` class is not available for me. `hyperref` is loaded ways too early and it has no table or figure caption at all... Please provide a compilable document that shows your issue and give us the information where this `uumthesis.cls` can be found

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the uumthesis.cls can be obtain from http://liantze.penguinattack.org/download_uumthesis.html

Comment: Looking into that class file I see nothing that prevents your request on a quick check. You must doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps your document class does not use `\thefigure` in captions.  Otherwise, see what `\meaning\thefigure` produces.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I've checked your suggestion -- the class uses the `caption` package and there is no indication it would omit `\thefigure` or is setting the figure number in a different manner.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how can I track changes that I made, for me to be able for me to identify my error? It is from sample.aux forsample.log?