# Floats: Figure labels matching the section they are in

Tags: sectioning, floats, cross-referencing

When I label my figures, they are labelled Figure 1, Figure 2, ...  How can I have the labelling match the section it comes from?  That is, if Figure 2 is in section 3, it will be labelled Figure 3.1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floats}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption = false}{subfig}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}
\caption{figure}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume) which explains `chngcntr` as suggested by @egreg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the `amsmath` package and issue the commands

```
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

to get `figure`, `table`, `equation` environments numbered separately within sections.

---

*Addendum*, motivated by a comment by @egreg: Instead of using the command `\numberwithin` of the `amsmath` package, you could load the `chngcntr` package and make use of its `\counterwithin` macro, as follows:

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
```

And, should you be working with a document class that numbers figures, tables, and equations separately within each chapter, say, and should you want to have these items numbered in plain, consecutive manner, you could do so by using the macro `\counterwithout`, as follows:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\counterwithout{equation}{section}
```

Comment: There is also the dedicated package `chngcntr` that has even more features than the simple `\numberwithing`.

Comment: Have at look at the answer to the question I linked above.

Comment: So `\counterwithin/out` can be used anywhere in the document then not just the preamble?

Comment: @dustin - I've edited the stuff in the addendum to better explain what the `\counterwithout` macro is about. At any rate, I'd use the command `\numberwithin` and `\counterwithin` only in the preamble. If you use them somewhere in the middle of the document, you'd risk confusing your readers terrible by having two different numbering systems.