# Is there a way to include a prefix to the figure number?

Tags: floats, numbering

The publisher requires that I have captions and references of resp. to figures that include the chapter number. So in chapter 27 it has to be figure 27.1, 27.2, ... in the captions. `\ref`has to be adapted as well. How can this be done?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but I am writing an article and want to pretend that I am chapter 27 in a book. Do I have to turn my paper into a book and claim I am in chapter 27?

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{27.\arabic{figure}`.

Comment: What you want is the "per section" of the linked question, then.

Comment: Just to know: are you working on something that will become a chapter of a book?