# Class amsbook continuous section numbering

Tags: numbering, amsbook

I am using `amsbook`. There, sections are numbered within chapters. For instance, if each of the first two chapters has 2 sections, then the sections are numbered as 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2.

I wonder how to make continuous section numbering 1, 2, 3, 4... (like the ones used in Halmos' measure theory book).

Comment: or [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

Comment: My effort to add conciseness by adding an MWE to the question just got deleted... Strange. Don't understand all the rejecting here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: You should be able to [view your suggested edit rejection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25285). My motivation for rejecting it is because the MWE did not replicate the output mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @Werner could have included a hack to get 1.1 instead of 1... ok. But it shows perfectly what has been the problem and would have saved Ruben a minute of typing...

Answer (score 2):

To Papiro: Taking into account that the question was tagged with amsbook, i won't say that this is a duplicate of the numerous sectioning threads, as far as it questions the possibility to change the sectioning in a specific documentclass. The answer is clearly, that one can aplly the "standard" solutions using `changectr` or `remreset`.

Here, i'd like to point out, that `remreset` is also viable, because in this case (with `amsbook`) there is no need to redefine the regarding `\the<cntr>`. So the solution would look like:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Test Chapter}
\section{First Test Section}
\section{Second Test Section}

\chapter{Second Test Chapter}
\section{Third Test Section}
\section{Fourth Test Section}

\end{document}
```