# Numeration of equations starting from 1 in each section

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering, theorems

I have two issues:

1. I want to change the numeration in section, now I have:

   [image]

   but I would like to have:

   > 10 Charakteryzacje zmiennej losowej
   >
   > 1. Definition
   > 2. Theorem

It means that the first number which indicates the section number is deleted.

2. Second issue is connected with the numeration too. Now I have that the numeration of all the equations spreads from 1 to ...  in the entire document. I want it to start from 1 in each new section.

Edit:
Inside my document I have:

```
 \newtheorem{tw}{Theorem}[section]
 \renewcommand{\theorem}{\arabic{tw}}
 \newtheorem{stw}[tw]{Stwierdzenie}
 \newtheorem{fakt}[tw]{Fakt}
 \newtheorem{lemat}[tw]{Lemat}

 \theoremstyle{definition}
 \newtheorem{df}[tw]{Definicja}
 \newtheorem{ex}[tw]{Przykład}
 \newtheorem{uw}[tw]{Uwaga}
 \newtheorem{at}[tw]{Wniosek}
```

and it doesn't work in a correct way, below is the class I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=2cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=2.5cm, marginparsep=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,linkbordercolor={0 0.9 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\sffamily \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}


\newtheorem{tw}{Theorem}[section]

\renewcommand{\theorem}{\arabic{tw}}

\newtheorem{stw}[tw]{Stwierdzenie}
\newtheorem{fakt}[tw]{Fakt}
\newtheorem{lemat}[tw]{Lemat}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{df}[tw]{Definicja}
\newtheorem{ex}[tw]{Przykład}
\newtheorem{uw}[tw]{Uwaga}
\newtheorem{at}[tw]{Wniosek}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the first question, if you have something like `\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}` in your document, add a line `\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\arabic{mytheorem}}`.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume (also deals with theorems)

Comment: For your update you need `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}` not `\renewcommand{\theorem}`

Comment: Note that this makes for awkward cross-references; you are forced to say ”Theorem 2 in Section 10” (in LaTeX code something like `Theorem~\ref{thm:a} in Section~\ref{sec:b}`) instead of the simpler “Theorem 10.2”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the numbering of equations, there is a user level interface provided by the `chngcntr` package.  Writing

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
```

will reset the equation counter at the beginning of each section, without changing its printing format.  [The package also has `\counterwithin` that would given numbering of the form "(section.equation)" which is not what you ask for.]

For the theorem numbering, the suggestion in kalkoeller's comment is the most appropriate.

Here is a minimal document:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}
  x = ay
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
  New theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{equation}
  t = x^2
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
  Last theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}
  s = t^3
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```