# How to number section and subsection properly?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want the outlook to be:

> 1 Introduction (section)
>   1.1 first subsection
>   1.2 second subsection.. etc
>
> 2 Chapter 2 (section)
>   2.1 subsection etc

But LaTeX is outputting

> 1.1 Introduction
>   1.1.1 subsection
>
> 1.2 Chapter 2
>   1.2.1 subsection

How do I fix my preamble?

**Addendum**  Heres the preamble so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onesided]{report} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
```

Comment: could you provide a Minimal working example? looks like you might use the wrong documentclass to get this by default

Comment: I guess you are working with a document class which provides the level `chapter` like `report` or `book`. If you want to avoid this level you can use a document class based on `article`.

Comment: looks like you need the `chngcntr` package.  [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/579) gives good information on how to use it.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- i'd agree with your comment except that the examples explicitly contain "Chapter 2".

Comment: Heres the preamble so far:\documentclass[12pt, onesided]{report}    
\usepackage{geometry}                  
\geometry{letterpaper}                     

\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

Comment: @Sabrina Please add the code as an edit to your answer, not in a comment. Also, please show how are you currently producing your sectional units to obtain the undesired result mentioned.

Comment: @Sabrina - I've copied the material from your most recent comment into the body of the posting. Hope that's OK. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments, you are using `report` (by the way, the class option is `oneside` and not `onesided`), so your higher sectional unit (assuming you won't be using `\part`) should be produced with `\chapter`; lower sectional units can be produced using `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, paragraph and `\subparagraph` (each one of these has its counter subordinated to the counter of the unit immediately above):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\paragraph{A test paragraph}
\subparagraph{A test subparagraph}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\section{Another test section}

\chapter{Another test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{Another test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you want to change the way chapter titles are formatted by suppressing the word "chapter" and placing the title in the same line with the number? If this is so, the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package can do the job for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{20pt}{20pt}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\paragraph{A test paragraph}
\subparagraph{A test subparagraph}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\section{Another test section}

\chapter{Another test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsection{Another test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, would be to use `article` instead of `report` and `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` (there's no `\chapter` in article).

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of the `article` document class. :-)