# Using decimal values for figure-captions (floats)

Tags: floats, counters

Given a figure and a section i need the figures in that section to be labeled in a `section.counter` manner. Example First figure, section 3. should be Figure 3.1
I can only use `\documentclass{article}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[paper=A4,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage[driver=pdftex, margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
%Preamble

\begin{document}

\date{}
\bibliography{Biblio}
\bibliographystyle{harvard}
\author{Aiden Strydom\\201103578}
\title{Artificial Intelligence\\Deliverable One: Agent Design}

%New page
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Background}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.8\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[angle=90,origin=c]    {AeroponicsUCDportrait.pdf}}
        %\caption{Figure 3.1 Aeroponics \textit{Use Cases}} 
        \caption[(3.1)]{A figure without list entry.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always make a complete document showing used classes. The format you describe is the default for report and book class (except before the first chapter)

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume) more general question.

Comment: Note that `article` class does not have `chapter`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `chngcntr` package. I stripped down the example to a minimum.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % the demo option is just for the example

\usepackage{chngcntr}
% number figures within sections
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\author{Aiden Strydom\\201103578}
\title{Artificial Intelligence\\Deliverable One: Agent Design}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section 1}

Some text

\section{Section 2}

Some text

\section{Section 3}

Some text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[angle=90,origin=c]{AeroponicsUCDportrait.pdf}

\caption{Aeroponics \textit{Use Cases}} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]