# How to set counter for paragraphs in sections?

Tags: numbering, sections-paragraphs

I want to counter paragraphs, always like x.y where x is section number and y is paragraph number in that section.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, text={18cm, 25cm}, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
foo
\paragraph{Definition % 1.1 %}
here is definition 1.1 and i need to reference it later as 1.1
\section{B}
 bar
 \paragraph{Definition % 2.1 %}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do you have `\subsection`s? What about `\subsubsection`s? What `\documentclass` are you using? Please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: `\paragraph` is defined to be the section level below `\subsubsection` It is possible to redefine things to lose subsection and subsection but it's a lot simpler to simply use them.

Comment: Consider using `amsthm`, and welcome to TeX.SX :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: ty! That was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options:

1. You can make `\paragraph` act in exactly the same way as `\subsection` by adding

   ```
   \let\paragraph\subsection
   ```

   to your document preamble. Or, simply use `\subsection` directly.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \let\paragraph\subsection% Make \paragraph act just like \subsection
   \begin{document}
   \section{A}
   foo
   \paragraph{Definition}
   Here is definition 1.1 and i need to reference it later as 1.1

   \section{B}
   bar
   \subsection{Definition}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Adjust the way `\paragraph`s are number by adding

   ```
   \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesection.\arabic{paragraph}}% How paragraphs are numbered
   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% Number up to paragraphs
   ```

   to your document preamble. The first command adjusts paragraphs to by numbered "like section"."paragraph". The second actually allows paragraphs to be numbered using the traditional sectional unit numbering condition.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesection.\arabic{paragraph}}% How paragraphs are numbered
   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% Number up to paragraphs
   \begin{document}
   \section{A}
   foo
   \paragraph{Definition}
   Here is definition 1.1 and i need to reference it later as 1.1

   \section{B}
   bar
   \subsection{C}
   foo bar
   \paragraph{Definition}
   foo bar foo

   \section{D}
   foo bar foo bar
   \subsection{E}
   bar foo bar foo
   \subsubsection{F}
   foo bar foo bar foo
   \paragraph{Definition}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The problem here is that you may confuse your readers if you mix `\subsection`s and `\paragraph`s, since they are numbered similarly. Moreover, their numbering doesn't adjust with each section (for example, restarting). If you want them to restart, then consult [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764). The suggestion there is to use

   ```
   \usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
   \counterwithout{paragraph}{section}
   ```

   Do this *before* redefining `\theparagraph`.

Comment: this is not why i need, because if paragraph is in subsection, the counting is wrong. If the paragraph is anywhere, it must always have number section.paragraphNumberInThatSection

Comment: @Krab: I've added something to that effect. However, I also mention why it seems problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with the `chngcntr` package.

Note that you need a combination of two commands:
`\counterwithout*{paragraph}{subsubsection}` tells LaTeX that you no longer want to reset the paragraph number when you start a new subsubsection (or any division greater than a subsubsection);
`\counterwithin*{paragraph}{section}` tells it that you want to reset it at the beginning of a new section (or anything above it, such as a chapter in a book).

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{paragraph}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout*{paragraph}{subsubsection}  %% stop resetting paragraph number with each new subsubsection
%\counterwithin*{paragraph}{section}        %% reset paragraph number for each section; only works with the preceding line!

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\paragraph{Definition 1}\label{par:1.1}
\subsection{Subsection}
\paragraph{Definition 2}\label{par:1.2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Definition 3}\label{par:1.3}

\section{Section}
\paragraph{Definition 4}\label{par:2.1}
\subsection{Subsection}
\paragraph{Definition 5}\label{par:2.2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Definition 6}\label{par:2.3}~

Reference to 1.1: \ref{par:1.1}

Reference to 1.2: \ref{par:1.2}

Reference to 1.3: \ref{par:1.3}

Reference to 2.1: \ref{par:2.1}

Reference to 2.2: \ref{par:2.2}

Reference to 2.3: \ref{par:2.3}
\end{document}
```