# Vertical table line is missing (tabularx and multirow)

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

Can anyone tell me, why my table is missing the vertical line on the right?
It has something to do with that `\multirow`, but i can't find it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, text={18cm, 25cm}, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\catcode`\-=12
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\bfseries offset & \bfseries velikost & \bfseries typ & \bfseries název & \bfseries popis\\
\hline
0 & 8 &  & (hlavička) & slovo pro správu, odkaz na třídu \\
\hline
8 & 1 & byte & A.a & \\
\hline
9 & 3 & & (zarovnání) & následují členy B, zarovnání na 4b\\
\hline
12 & 2 & char & B.a & \multirow{3}{4cm}{B má double, vyplnění 4 bajtové mezery}\\
\cline{1-4}
14 & 1 & byte & B.b\\
\cline{1-4}
15 & 1 & & (zarovnání)\\
\hline
16 & 8 & double & B.d & \\
\hline
24 & 4 & A & B.c & \\
\hline
28 & 4 & & (zarovnání) & finální zarovnání na 8 bajtů\\        
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as you have done [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/how-to-set-counter-for-paragraphs-in-sections). (We can't know `\code` is defined, for example.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: done

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: that \catcode is there cause otherweise i got some error from \cline

Comment: you are missing a `&` at the end the two rows after your multirow

Comment: If you prefer to generate quickly a complex LaTeX tables online with our generator http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ or a plugin for Ex­cel at link https://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by a comment provided by David Carlisle, viz., to insert `&` in two places.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `&` at the end the two rows after your `\multirow` You need teh empty cells to carry the vertical rules.