# Start table number in whole digits for each chapter seprately

Tags: floats, numbering

I want to show table number starting from 1 to so on seprately on each chapter. I am trying to use setcounter, but its not giving the desired results.

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{4}

\chapter{One}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{I want to give number Table-1}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{50pt}r}
\hline 
\textbf{Province} & \textbf{Import }\textbf{\scriptsize{}('000' USD)} & 
\textbf{Percent}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Punjab &  393.8  & 21.35\tabularnewline
Sindh &  521.4  & 72.53\tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Grand Total} & \textbf{ 321.2 } & \textbf{ 100.00 }\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{I want to give number Table-2}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{50pt}r}
\hline 
\textbf{Province} & \textbf{Import }\textbf{\scriptsize{}('000' USD)} & 
\textbf{Percent}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Punjab &  393.8  & 21.35\tabularnewline
Sindh &  521.4  & 72.53\tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Grand Total} & \textbf{ 321.2 } & \textbf{ 100.00 }\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{I want to give number Table-1}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{50pt}r}
\hline 
\textbf{Province} & \textbf{Import }\textbf{\scriptsize{}('000' USD)} & 
\textbf{Percent}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Azad Jammu \& Kashmir &  2.1  & 0.03\tabularnewline
Balochistan &  1.6  & 0.08\tabularnewline
EPZ &  9.7  & 0.41\tabularnewline
\hline 
\textbf{Grand Total} & \textbf{ 321.2 } & \textbf{ 100.00 }\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question that shows how to get 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2 or 1,2,3,4,5 this question asks for 1,2,3,1,2

Comment: For reference, the suggested but not actual dupe is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Answer (score 6):

I think you just want

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
```

so that the chapter number is not in front of the table number, the counter is already reset each chapter.

Comment: now there is another problem, i have tables and longtables in my documents, while marking the tables numbers, Latex doesn't consider the order in which I placed the tables. It gives first number to tables, then to longtables. how to overcome this problem?

Comment: It is a documented feature that floats can float past longtables and if they do the numbering is out of sequence, you either need to put \clearpage before the longtable to stop floats going past or help latex with the numbering by putting \setcounter{table}{5} or whatever number you need just before the floats with the wrong numbers, until latex gets back in sync (use one less than the number you want as the caption always adds 1)

Comment: now its working well by putting \clearpage just before the longtable.

Answer (score 1):

If additionally you want to reset the table numbering on each chapter, you can use the `chngcntr` package:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt, openany]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{table}{4}

\chapter{One}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{I want to give number Table-1}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{50pt}r}
\hline
\textbf{Province} & \textbf{Import }\textbf{\scriptsize{}('000' USD)} &
\textbf{Percent}\tabularnewline
\hline
Punjab & 393.8 & 21.35\tabularnewline
Sindh & 521.4 & 72.53\tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Grand Total} & \textbf{ 321.2 } & \textbf{ 100.00 }\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{I want to give number Table-2}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{50pt}r}
\hline
\textbf{Province} & \textbf{Import }\textbf{\scriptsize{}('000' USD)} &
\textbf{Percent}\tabularnewline
\hline
Punjab & 393.8 & 21.35\tabularnewline
Sindh & 521.4 & 72.53\tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Grand Total} & \textbf{ 321.2 } & \textbf{ 100.00 }\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{I want to give number Table-1}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedleft}p{50pt}r}
\hline
\textbf{Province} & \textbf{Import }\textbf{\scriptsize{}('000' USD)} &
\textbf{Percent}\tabularnewline
\hline
Azad Jammu \& Kashmir & 2.1 & 0.03\tabularnewline
Balochistan & 1.6 & 0.08\tabularnewline
EPZ & 9.7 & 0.41\tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Grand Total} & \textbf{ 321.2 } & \textbf{ 100.00 }\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is the default that the counter is reset by a new chapter.

Comment: @Herbert: you're right. As it was asked for, I forgot to check that point and simply adapted an answer to a similar problem, for the article class, where there is no \chapter…