# How do I reset the footnote cross-referencing counter for each chapter?

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, chapters, counters

I am writing my thesis in the document class scrbook, and have the footnotes counter set to start again from 1 in each chapter. However when I reference a source more than once within a chapter, it cross-references back to the very first occurrence of this source even if this was in a previous chapter, instead of to the first occurrence in the current chapter.

In my MWE the source `Al Bashir' is in a footnote in Chapter 1, and then again in two footnotes in Chapter 2. In Chapter 2 it should give the full citation, and then the following footnote should cross reference this first one in Chapter 2 and NOT refer back to the footnote in Chapter 1.

How do I re-set the cross-referencing counter as well as the footnote counter for each chapter?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,a4paper,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola, indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testingbiblio.bib} %necessary for Oscola
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes} %necessary for Oscola
\usepackage[noautomatic,nonewpage,splitindex]{imakeidx}

\makeatletter   % the commands to ensure footnotes start new numbering at each chapter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget elit gravida, pharetra mauris at, malesuada dui. Sed vitae tortor ante. Quisque sollicitudin accumsan nulla sit amet mattis.\footcite{Tadic} In eu vulputate sem, in sagittis arcu. Nullam fringilla libero non nisi aliquam, eget pulvinar arcu pulvinar. Ut tristique ullamcorper nisl, vitae cursus nulla varius vel. Proin non rhoncus risus.\footcite{AlBashirIndictment}

\chapter{Second}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footcite{Vaillancourt} Proin non rhoncus risus.\footcite{AlBashirIndictment} Phasellus eget elit gravida, pharetra mauris at, malesuada dui.\footcite{AlBashirIndictment}


\end{document}
```

My bib file is:

```
@jurisdiction{AlBashirIndictment,
title = {Public Redacted Version of Prosecutor's Application for Warrant of Arrest under Art. 58},
shorttitle = {Al Bashir Application for Warrant of Arrest},
date = {2008-09-12},
number = {ICC-02/05-157},
court = {Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate= {ICC},
keywords={ICC}
}

@jurisdiction{Tadic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Dusko Tadi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
shorttitle = {Tadi\'{c} Appeals Judgment},
date = {1999-07-15},
number = {IT-94-1-A},
court = {Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate= {ICTY},
keywords={ICTY}
}

@jurisdiction{Vaillancourt,
title = {R. v Vaillancourt},
shorttitle = {Vaillancourt},
date = {1987},
court = {Supreme Court of Canada},
reporter = {S.C.R.},
volume = {2},
pages = {636},
pagination = {paragraph},
location = {Canada},
}
```

Comment: more than you ever wanted to know about resetting counters: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is burried deeply in the manual of oscola, see p. 9:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola, indexing=cite,
 citereset=chapter]{biblatex}
```

Please note: "citereset=chapter".

Oh, and by the way, this code is not necessary:

```
\makeatletter   % the commands to ensure footnotes start new numbering at each chapter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

I suggest to add "english" to the global options and

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
```

to your preamble.

Please make sure your bib-file has UTF-8 encoding.