# Numbering equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

If I am writing a LaTeX document on TexMaker and I want to number my equation but most probably I will be adding details later on and I do not want to fall into retyping it all over again. So if for example I have an equation and currently called equation (1.2) that I want to refer later as in the following sentence "As you can see in (1.2)" but then I had to edit my document in a way that it becomes (1.3) now instead of (1.2) what should I do in order to avoid editing large number of equations and my reference to them?

Comment: How are you currently numbering your equations? Are you using the `equation` environment?

Comment: Use the `\label` and `\ref` commands (and possibly `\eqref` from the `amsmath` package). http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing

Comment: and if I want to label them as (1.1) instead of (1)?

Also please write it as an answer so I can choose it as best answer because it answered my question.

Comment: @Werner I haven't yet numbered anything

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX supports this cross-referencing mechanism out-of-the-box. Fundamentally you should use

```
\begin{equation}
  <your equation here> \label{<label>}
\end{equation}
```

for single-line equations, and [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align`-style environment for multi-line equations (you can also use it for single-line equations). For example,

```
\begin{align}
  <eqn 1 LHS> & <eqn 1 RHS> \label{<label1>} \\
  <eqn 2 LHS> & <eqn 2 RHS> \label{<label2>} \\
  ...
\end{align}
```

See the [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) for a host of examples on the `amsmath` `align`-environment usages, as well as others.

The above allows you to use `\ref{<label>}` inside your document to obtain the number/label associated with `<label>`. It's better to `\usepackage{amsmath}` and to use `\eqref{<label>}` just because this includes the `(..)`.

`\label`s are stored in the `.aux`, and may only settle after a second compilation. So, if things move around, make sure to compile twice. See [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764).

If you want to change the numbering of the equations (from say `(1.1)` to `(1)`), see [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764). The [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) is useful for adjusting the resetting of the numbering scheme.