# How to make numbering of equations with just one number in each chapter?

Tags: numbering

My report has 8 chapters. I want each chapter to have equations from number 1 and just showing with a simple number e.g. 1 without dependency on chapter number (e.g. (1.1)) or without dependency on section number (e.g. (1.1.1))? Just a simple number, and with each chapter starting from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered here: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

But here is a minimal example which should do what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\begin{equation}
    1-1=0
\end{equation}

\chapter{Two}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This will not make equation numbers start again from 1 at each chapter.

Comment: why use the package?

Comment: True egreg, thanks for notice. I edited the code and now it should do the job.

Comment: As is the number does not restart, if you remove `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` then it works as required