# how to add figure numbers in listoffigures continously

Tags: table-of-contents

I have used `\listoffigures` in my report and the list contains indexing like `2.1` if it belongs to `chapter 2` `first image` and `5.4` for `chapter 5` ,`fourth image`,
how can I change this to `continuous` `arabic` `numeral` `indexing` like `1,2,3,...` without taking consideration for the chapter and figure number in that chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has already been asked and answered: [Question Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
```