# Change equation number to reset at part

Tags: numbering, counters

I would like the equation numbers to run through chapters and reset at a new part. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried the following shown below however it still resets with the chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{part}~--~\arabic{equation}}
\counterwithin*{equation}{part}


\begin{document}

\part{one}

\chapter{one one}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\chapter{two two}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\part{two}

\chapter{one one}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\chapter{two two}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)

Answer (score 4):

`\counterwithin{equation}{part}` does **not** remove the `equation` counter from the `chapter` reset list. It must be kicked out explicitly with

`\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}`.

The counter formatting `\theequation` should be changed afterwards then, since `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}`. Or use `\counterwithout*{equation}{chapter}`

Here's the (modified) MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{equation}{part}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{part}~--~\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\part{one}

\chapter{one one}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\chapter{two two}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\part{two}

\chapter{one one}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}

\chapter{two two}
\begin{equation}
    1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]