# Bibliography as Chapter

Tags: bibliographies, captions

I am trying to make simple bibliography list. So, for example, I have in text a reference point [1] which needs to appear in the bibliography list automatically.

In the document, I used the following code with `\usepackage{hyperref}` inserted:

```
\cite{1}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1} 
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
\textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
\end{thebibliography}
```

So far, I experienced a few problems:

- the Bibliography does not appear in Index.
- the Bibliography page does not appear as a chapter

Comment: You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the Bibliography page does not appear as a chapter"?

Comment: As for the numbering of photos: I think photos are a non-standart construct, so without having a MWE its hard to guess, but if they are handled similar to figures, the following answer might help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/36296

Comment: Offtopic, but usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are referring to the table of contents, when you speak of "index". To add the bibliography there, you can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}`. As an alternative, you could use tools like `biblatex` which has options to add the it automatically to the toc.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{normal chap}
    \cite{1}

    \begin{thebibliography}{1} 
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
        \bibitem{1} Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993. 
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]