# Algorithm numbering appears continues in different chapter

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I am working on the thesis and have four algorithms, two in Chapter 3 and two in Chapter four. The algorithms appear 3.1, 3.2, 4.3 and 4.4. When I remove Chapter 3 from the thesis, the 4.3 and 4.4 become 3.1 and 3.2 respectively. 
How to make it 3.1, 3.2 and 4.1, 4.2?

I do not know how I can submit the MWE for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the following setup:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}% Just for this example
\chapter{Third chapter}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{First algorithm}% 3.1
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Second algorithm}% 3.2
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Fourth chapter}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Third algorithm}% 4.3
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Fourth algorithm}% 4.4
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The above reproduces your problem - only adding the `chapter` counter representation to your setup without making it reset with every new `\chapter`. This is the default behaviour of [`algorithm`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) - providing continuous numbering of algorithms throughout the document, since there's not that many algorithms in any document in general.

To change this, you can either use [`chngcnt`](//ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) or [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) together with

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}% also works with \usepackage{amsmath}
\counterwithin{algorithm}{chapter}
```

and remove the `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}`. For more information, see [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/5764).