# How to number figures without leading zeros in documentclass scrbook

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, formatting, numbering, scrbook

I am using the documentclass {srcbook} and by default the section and figure numbering starts with leading zeros (so 0.1; 0.2 etc.). I found a great solution for avoiding that with the section numbers but so far could not find one for the numbering of figures and tables.

Has anyone come across a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)

Comment: Please show us a **short**, **compilable** code with creation of chapters and sections. Use package `blindtext` or simular for dummy text (read the documentation with`texdoc blindtext`). Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you use `book`, `scrbook` or another book class, the first level of sectioning is `\chapter`; sections, tables, figures are numbered within chapters by default. If you have no `\chapter` command before your sections, tables etc, the chapter counter remains at its initial value zero, and this is the leading zero that you see. You have several options: (A) raise all headings one level (`\section`s become `\chapter`s, `\subsection`s become `\section`s etc), (B) use an article class, like `article`, `scrartcl` (C) change numbering as Werner suggests.

Comment: the default is not to to have leading zeros, if you are getting leading zeros then something is wrong with your markup, probably as gernot says, you have not used `\chapter`.