# Latex Numberwithin does not work for first Figure

Tags: floats, numbering

I'm trying to write a document for my laboratory for the college and this is my code.

```
\section{Impuls- und Spungantwort für die drei Tiefpässe}    


 \begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{../durchfuehrung/lc_puls_flach.png} 
\caption{Anregung des LC-Tiefpasses (flach) mit einem Puls}
\label{LC Flach Puls}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{../durchfuehrung/lc_puls_steil.png} 
 \caption{Anregung des LC-Tiefpasses (steil) mit einem Puls}
\label{LC Steil Puls}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
 \end{figure} \newpage
```

In the produced pdf file the numbering of the figure is

> 2.1

and

> 2.1.2

The numbering should be **2.1.1** and **2.1.2** I can't find the problem.

This is my main tex file.

```
\input{header}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{0pt}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
pdfborder={0 0 0}
}
\numberwithin{figure} {section}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{kapitel/titelseite_Standard}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\input{kapitel/vorbereitung}
\chapter{Durchführung und Auswertung}
\input{kapitel/LV_4_2_1}
\input{kapitel/LV_4_2_2}
\input{kapitel/LV_4_2_3}

%\include{kapitel/nuetzliches}
%\include{kapitel/blindtext}

%\bibliography{biblio/biblio}
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap into `\section` and `\subsection` to reset the way the figure counter works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr,lipsum}

\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\counterwithin{figure}{section}\oldsection}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}\oldsubsection}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 1.1
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 1.2
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 1.1.1
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 1.1.2
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 1.2.1
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 1.2.2

\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 2.1
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 2.2
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 2.1.1
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 2.1.2
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 2.2.1
\begin{figure}\caption{A caption}\end{figure}% 2.2.2

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\counterrwithin` in preamble instead using it in every figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, margin=2in}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\input{file1.tex}
\section{section01}
\input{file1.tex}
\input{file1.tex}

\end{document}
```

And file1.tex :

```
\subsection{Smiles}    

\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.1\textwidth]{smile.png} 
\caption{Smile:)}
\label{smile01}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.1\textwidth]{smile.png} 
\caption{Another smile}
\label{smile02}
\end{figure}
```

Resulting figures are numbered as 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2

[image: result]

[1][Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

Comment: That works. But I have a main tex file and if I create subsections the figure will have the numbering of the section...

Comment: Then try `\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}`

Comment: But I have different figures in different sections and if I declare somethin in the preamble the figure numbering is for every figure the same

Comment: I've changed the answer a little. Try this.

Comment: That seems good but what if you want to place a figure in a section. The numbering will be 1.1.1 but should be 1.1 because of the counterwithin subsection

Comment: @skop: Please be more clear about what you're after. Do you want the figure to be numbered within the sectional unit that it is placed? That is, if a figure is within section 2, they should be numbered 2.1, 2.2, ... If other figures are placed inside subsection 2.3, they should be numbered 2.3.1, 2.3.2, ... Should numbering be restarted with every new sectional unit?

Comment: @Werner, yes that's what I want. And it is working if I place the command numberwithin {figure} {section/subsection} but whatever I do my first Figure in the first subsection of the second section won't be 2.1.1 but 2.1. Sorry for the misunderstanding, English is not my native language.