# Continuous Counter for Figures

Tags: floats, theorems, counters

How to float a figure counter such that it displays section than counter with figures, theorems and definitions? e.g

Figure 1.1

Definition 1.2

Figure 1.3

Algorithm 1.4

Theorem 1.5

etc.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it has be exhaustively answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume).

Comment: I think an answer to this will depend on how you define the `definition`, `algorithm` and `theorem` environments, so if you could make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it would make it possible for people to answer properly. (I.e. make a short code  starting with `\documentclass`, containing all necessary packages and definitions for `definition`, `algorithm` and `theorem`, but no more than that, and in the document part itself, just add an empty `figure` with caption, and empty/one liner theorems etc.)

Comment: Is there any news on this or shall this be closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've understood the question as `definition`, `figure`, `algorithm` etc. should either share the same counter or are stepped with each other.

I use a `coupled` counter approach from `xassoccnt` package, forming a group of coupled counters  with `\DeclareCoupledCountersGroupName` and assigning the relevant counters to this group.

Please note that due to the floating behaviour of `figure` environment the order of appearance and numbering is not the same then! Consider to use something like `\FloatBarrier` from `picins` package in order to prevent this!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareCoupledCountersGroup{figtheoexadef}
\DeclareCoupledCounters[name=figtheoexadef]{theorem,figure,example,definition}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo section}
\begin{definition}{Foo}
\blindtext
\end{definition}

\begin{figure}
\blindtext

\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{theorem}{Foo}
\blindtext
\end{theorem}               %

\begin{example}{Foo}
\blindtext
\end{example}               %

\begin{figure}
\blindtext
\caption{Yet another figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Foobar section}

\begin{figure}
\blindtext
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{theorem}{Foo}
\blindtext
\end{theorem}               %

\begin{example}{Foo}
\blindtext
\end{example}               %

\begin{figure}
\blindtext
\caption{More figures}
\end{figure}

\begin{definition}{Foo}
\blindtext
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]