# Label and numbering in Latex

Tags: numbering, counters, labels

I'm returning to LaTeX after many years away from it, and hope you can answer this question.

I am writing a catalogue that has a lot of cross references that need to be individually numbered (probably 5000+), so using the `\label` and `\ref` commands will be very useful. I've also used sections and subsections to make the catalogue manageable.

I would simply like to label items starting at number 1, 2, 3 etc. and going to 5000+. I've used `\label{itema}\textbf{\ref{itema}}` to label and reference the items but this adds in 0.1.1 as its in a subsection, and then restarts the numbering in the next section/subsection.

Any suggestions for how I just get `\label` to label items as 1, 2, 3 etc. without restarting for each section, subsection etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Perhaps this would help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? The code you've shown will give `0.1.1` or whatever for every item in the subsection as you don't increment any counter, but just use the subsection's, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example in your question would make it a lot easier to help. And more likely the answer would be of some use to you.

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitems}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myitems]{label=\arabic*, font=\bfseries, resume}
\begin{document}
\section{Living}
\subsection{Animals}
\begin{myitems}
  \item\label{enum:wombat} Wombat\footnote{Not usually found in terraced houses (\ref{enum:terrace}).}
  \item\label{enum:parrot} Parrot
\end{myitems}
\subsection{Plants}
\begin{myitems}
  \item\label{enum:cactus} Cactus\footnote{Not suitable for igloo-dwellers (\ref{enum:igloo}).}
  \item\label{enum:willow} Willow
  \item\label{enum:ivy} Ivy
\end{myitems}
\subsection*{Important notes}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Note 1
  \item Note 2
\end{enumerate}
\section{Homes}
\begin{myitems}
  \item\label{enum:igloo} Igloo
  \item\label{enum:terrace} Terraced house
  \item\label{enum:tree} Tree house
\end{myitems}
\end{document}
```

[image: lists]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the way it numbers is how I want it too, but the problem is it creates a list. I'll give an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Okay to clarify what I am trying to do. I want continuous numbering as suggested in the previous answer, however the original \labels need to be in a table (as they are essentially captions, but I want to avoid using the caption command as sometimes there will not be an image).

I then want to reference these labels in the text. The text may be in another table or just general text (which is in a table or tabbed).

So here's what I want to achieve:

456 Koala
457 Kangaroo etc. (these are the original labels)

Then in the text, No. 456 and 457 were released individually and in...

Comment: Probably I don't really understand what you want then. But I see you've found a solution, so that's good :-).

Comment: I like Wombats. +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've achieve it in this way:

In the header I've added:

```
\newcounter{koala}
\newenvironment{koala}[1][]{\refstepcounter{koala}\\
   \textbf{\thekoala #1} }
```

Then in the body:

```
\includegraphics{koala1.jpg}
\begin{koala}
\label{koala1}Koala in a Tree
\end{koala}
```

I can then reference the item however I want to.

I may not be the elegant solution to my problem, but it does the job.

If anybody can suggest another solution, please do.

Comment: Why the group? That seems very odd.

Comment: Why not e.g. `\newcommand*\koala[1][]{\refstepcounter{koala}\textbf{\thekoala #1} }`? Then `\koala ... \koala[Koala]` or whatever. You certainly shouldn't have the `\\ ` there. Aside from anything else, `\\ ` should not be used to end lines outside `tabular` and `array` etc. So if these are *all* in `tabular`s, that's fine. But otherwise, it is wrong. Also, it is better to say `\includegraphics{koala1}` without the extension.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I'm still getting to grips with LaTeX having been away from it for nearly 15 years.