# memoir chapter based figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, memoir

when using `\documentclass[12pt,article, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}`. The `article` option addition interferes with the figure numbering. Removing it fixes the numbering but changes the look of the document and increases the page count. Any suggestions for keeping the look from article and retaining the numbering without it?

With the format x.n: 'x' being the chapter number in which the figure is in and 'n' as the figure number in the chapter?

I have tried `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` which changes 'n' to per section number with n being renewed for the new section but 'x' in missing.

code with continues figure numbers

```
\documentclass[12pt, article, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png,.psv,.PNG}
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*} % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{ upgreek }
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newpage
\chapter{Abstract}
stuff
\clearpage
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
stuff
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
%\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\mainmatter
\chapter {Introduction}
stuff
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\begin{figure}[h]
Figure One
\caption{Figure One}
\end{figure}

\section{Section Two}
\begin{figure}[h]
Figure Two
\caption{Figure Two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

this provides figure numbering as shown

[image]
by removing article  the list of figure changes to the desired numbering
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

Comment: By default memoir numbers figures by chapter.number, if you have something else, then please update your question with a full minimal example that we can copy and test.

Comment: I found the issue, the suggestions on to the link don't work as intended if \documentclass[12pt,article, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}  is being used. The 'article' addition interferes with the numbering. Removing it fixes the numbering but changes the looks of the document and increase the page count. Any suggestions for keeping the look from article and retaining the numbering without it?

Comment: Please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question that shows that the `\counterwithin` solution of the linked page does not work.

Comment: You've not used `\counterwithin` as mentioned in the `memoir` note of the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/9057) to the linked question. And please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) in the [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help). And please [reduce the example to the needed lines](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: ok I think I have fixed the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `article` option of `memoir` with `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, `\frontmatter` still does a `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` but `\mainmatter` does not reactivate `\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}`. So you have to add the command after `\mainmatter` on your own:

```
\documentclass[12pt, article, a4paper, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*} % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\chapter{Abstract}
\listoffigures
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\mainmatter
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\chapter {Introduction}
stuff
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\begin{figure}[h]
Figure One
\caption{Figure One}
\end{figure}

\section{Section Two}
\begin{figure}[h]
Figure Two
\caption{Figure Two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But note: If you add `\newpage` or `\clearpage` before every `\chapter` it would make more sense to not use option `article` and remove those `\newpage` and `\clearpage`. In this case you also would not need the `\counterwithin`.