# Table counter doesn't start from 1

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable

I used a template from overleaf, I can not figure out which setting made this problem happen, so [here is is the document](https://www.overleaf.com/13047295sndbtgqszqsk). 
And the problem is in the file:

> Chapters/Chapter1.tex

on line 30:

```
\caption{Related work \label{table:related_work}} \\
```

[image]

I tried:

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: The first `1` is the chapter number. Adding `renewcommand{\thetable}\arabic{table}` to your preamble should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [referenced question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume) (that has already been asked and answered), I end up doing this:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}% Continuous numbering of figures
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}% Continuous numbering of tables
```

---

Old solution (not as good as above, agreed with the comment):

Thanks to Bernard, adding the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
```

to file

> main.tex

line 66 did the trick.

Comment: But the first table in chapter 2 will again be numbered 1.