# Equation number within proof environment while aligning all the equations?

Tags: equations, align, proof-package

I know equation numbering is possible in a `proof` environment, as shown below in MWE1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
A+B=C
\begin{equation}
G(t)=L\gamma!\,t^{-\gamma}+t^{-\delta}\eta(t) \qedhere
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

But I want the equations to be aligned. Thus I need `\begin{align}...\end{align}`, as shown in the MWE2 below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
\mu &= np \nonumber\\
&= \textonehalf n;\nonumber\\
\begin{equation}
\sigma &= \sqrt{np\left(1-p\right)}\\
\end{equation}
&=  \textonehalf \sqrt{n};\nonumber\\
Z &= \dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \nonumber\\
&= \frac{X-\textonehalf n}{\textonehalf \sqrt{n}};\nonumber\\
\vartriangle Z&= \frac{\left(X+1\right)-\textonehalf n}{\textonehalf 
\sqrt{n}} - \frac{X-\textonehalf n}{\textonehalf \sqrt{n}} \nonumber\\
\begin{equation}
\vartriangle Z&= \dfrac{1}{\textonehalf \sqrt{n}}\\
\end{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \vartriangle Z &= 0
\end{align} 
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

But there is an error in MWE2. How do I assign equation numbers to some selected equations in a proof environment while aligning all the equations? I want the equation number so that I can label (`\label{}`) such equations and reference (`\ref{}`) it within the document. I want the alignment along the equation signs, so that it will look aesthetical and professional.

Comment: `equation` had not be nested in `align` environment.

Comment: `\textonehalf` should not be used in math mode. If you want a small fraction, use `\tfrac{1}{2}`.

Comment: You've received some good answers, but I'm confused about why you were trying to nest the `equation` environment in the first place.  The only thing I can think of is that you wanted the numbering provided by `equation`.  But surely you realize all those `\nonumber` commands were what was removing the equation numbers in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zarko mentioned, the `equation` environment must not be used in an `align` environment. Just removing the equation environment works for me:
[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\numberthis}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\arabic{equation}}}
\newcommand{\labeln}[1]{\numberthis\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\mathonehalf}{\ensuremath{\frac{1}{2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
    \mu &= np \\
    &= \mathonehalf n;\\
    \sigma &= \sqrt{np\left(1-p\right)} \labeln{eq:sigma}\\
    &=  \mathonehalf \sqrt{n};\\
    Z &= \dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\\
    &= \frac{X-\mathonehalf n}{\mathonehalf \sqrt{n}};\\
    \vartriangle Z&= \frac{\left(X+1\right)-\mathonehalf n}{\mathonehalf 
    \sqrt{n}} - \frac{X-\mathonehalf n}{\mathonehalf \sqrt{n}}\\
    \vartriangle Z&= \dfrac{1}{\mathonehalf \sqrt{n}} \labeln{eq:dz}\\
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \vartriangle Z &= 0 \labeln{eq:limdz}
\end{align} 
\end{proof}

References to $\sigma$ \eqref{eq:sigma} and $\Delta Z$ \eqref{eq:dz}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: And an alternative to all that `\nonumber` would be `align*` and then `\tag{1234}` the appropriate line.

Comment: How do I label each equation so that I can reference it?

Comment: @economia I added the labels.

Comment: @Teepeemm -- while `\tag` certainly works, it rather defeats the latex concept of automatic numbering, in that if you shift the equations around, you will have to retag them manually.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could I use `\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{(\arabic{equation})}`?  I'd rather not have to type `\nonumber` six or more times just to have one line that I can refer to.

Comment: @Teepeemm -- yes, that should be possible.  certainly worth trying, although i haven't time to do so now.

Comment: @Teepeemm, @economia: I added your suggested way to label the equations. Also I corrected the `\textonehalf`s.

Comment: thanks for your answers, the equation number counter now fall along proof count. For example, I have (0.1),(0.2),...,(0.n) before the first proof and (1.1),(1.2),...,(1.n) after the first proof and (2.1),(2.2),...,(2.n) after the second proof etc. I rather want the equation number to count after section.

Comment: @economia By now, you could do a little research on your own and maybe ask a new question, as this is not really related to your initial question. Anyhow, this should be easily possible by changing the `\numberthis` command: `\newcommand{\numberthis}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}}`. And also, please don't forget to accept an answer

Comment: @economia Referring to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume), one should use the package `chngcntr` and the provided commands from there. Now you're on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Is it this you want? You can get small fractions in math mod ewith `\tfrac`. But in this context, I'd recommend the `\mfrac` command from  `nccmath`.

Also: preferably, use the `utf8` encoding nowadays. Don't nest an `equation` environment in `align`. Needless to load `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb`. Just use this simplified code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{proof}
 \begin{align}
 \mu &= np \nonumber\\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}n;\nonumber\\
 \sigma &= \sqrt{np (1-p )}\\
 &= \mfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{n};\nonumber\\
 Z &= \dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \nonumber\\
 &= \frac{X-\textonehalf n}{\textonehalf \sqrt{n}};\nonumber\\
 \Delta Z&= \frac{\left(X+1\right)-\textonehalf n}{\textonehalf
\sqrt{n}} - \frac{X-\textonehalf n}{\textonehalf \sqrt{n}} \nonumber\\
\Delta Z&= \dfrac{1}{\textonehalf \sqrt{n}}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Delta Z &= 0
\end{align}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `nccmath` load `amsmath` if i recall correctly :-)

Comment: @Zarko: You're quite right. It's a quite useful small package, in my opinion.

Comment: yes, it is. recently i use it quite often. +1 for nice answer

Comment: @economia: You must have something that makes the equation number depend on another counter. Could you post a small code  demonstrating the problem?