# book class with continuous page numbering throughout chapters

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, books

There are a few related entries but I cannot find a solution, sorry it's quite urgent.

I'm trying to achieve a continuous numbering of pages, figures and tables, rather than the numbering restarting at each chapter.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,english]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}



\usepackage[a4paper,verbose, asymmetric, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{verbatim}   
\usepackage{float}     
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{expdlist}
\usepackage{acronym_expdlist} 
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}


\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliographystyle{copernicus}

%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} %add bibliography to table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

\input{page_layout_definition.tex}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{3cm}%
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\raggedleft
\textsf{university\\
faculty\\
department}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{flushleft}
\Large \textsf{title}\\

\end{flushleft}
\hrule    

\bigskip
 \LARGE\noindent \textsf{name} \hfill
\bigskip

\normalsize
% 
% % Footer
\vfill
\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}%
   %\includegraphics*[width=2.0cm]{intec}%       % intec logo
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{9cm}
 \raggedleft
 %\textsf{text1 \\
 %text2: \\
 %text3 \\
 %text4}
\end{minipage}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\normalsize

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{3cm}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\raggedleft
\textsf{university\\
faculty\\
department}
\end{minipage}
\\[2cm]

\noindent \begin{tabular}{ @{} l l}
name \\
\end{tabular}
\\[2cm]


\noindent university \\
\noindent faculty
\\[0.3cm]
\noindent add1 \\
\noindent add2
\noindent add3
\\[0.3cm]

\\[4cm]
\noindent

\vfill

\begin{minipage}{2.0cm}%
    %\includegraphics*[width=2.0cm]{intec}%       % logo
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{9cm}
\raggedleft
\textsf{thesis\\
text}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\selectlanguage{english}
\hyphenation{every-where}
\frontmatter
\chapter{}
\vspace{0.35in}

\begin{flushright}{\emph{place, date\\
name}}
\end{flushright}
\selectlanguage{english}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\listoffigures
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\listoftables
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\include{acronyms}

\clearpage      
\thispagestyle{empty}  
\mbox{}        
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\mainmatter


\selectlanguage{english}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

\newcommand\fdtsvrightmarktmp{{\scshape\small Chapter }}
\renewcommand\evenpagerightmark{{\scshape\small\chaptername\ \thechapter}}
\renewcommand\oddpageleftmark{{\scshape\small\leftmark}}

\baselineskip 13.0pt

\include{ch1/ch1}
\include{ch2/ch2}
\include{ch3/ch3}
\include{ch4/ch4}
\include{ch5/ch5}
\include{ch6/ch6}
\include{ch7/ch7}
\include{ch8/ch8}
\include{ch9/ch9}


%\printbibliography
%\bibliographystyle{copernicus}

\renewcommand\evenpagerightmark{{}}
\renewcommand\oddpageleftmark{{}}

\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```

page_layout_definition.tex

```
\geometry{body={11.5cm,18.92cm}}
\geometry{twoside,marginpar=0.0cm,marginparsep=0.0cm}

\setlength{\textwidth}{11.5cm}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.8}

\renewcommand{\subfigcapskip}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\newcommand\oddpageleftmark{}
\newcommand\evenpagerightmark{}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\oddpageleftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\evenpagerightmark}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \def\PARstart#1#2{\begingroup\def\par{\endgraf\endgroup\lineskiplimit=0pt}
 \setbox2=\hbox{\uppercase{#2} }\newdimen\tmpht \tmpht \ht2
 \advance\tmpht by \baselineskip\font\hhuge=cmr10 at \tmpht
 \setbox1=\hbox{{\hhuge #1}}
 \count7=\tmpht \count8=\ht1\divide\count8 by 1000 \divide\count7 by\count8
 \tmpht=.001\tmpht\multiply\tmpht by \count7\font\hhuge=cmr10 at \tmpht
 \setbox1=\hbox{{\hhuge #1}} \noindent \hangindent1.05\wd1
 \hangafter=-2 {\hskip-\hangindent \lower1\ht1\hbox{\raise1.0\ht2\copy1}
 \kern-0\wd1}\copy2\lineskiplimit=-1000pt}

\newcommand{\usefn}[1]{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}}


\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small \itshape \mdseries \rmfamily}
\renewcommand{\subcapsize}{\footnotesize \itshape \mdseries \rmfamily}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\@removefromreset`?  Either `\makeatletter\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}\makeatother` or `\makeatletter\@removefromreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother` (or both) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just adding these two to the preamble did not change anything. Was that the right way to try? I have added the page layout file to the above example, maybe this is preventing the option to work?

Comment: This should have changed the section numbering, at a minimum... so I would be surprised if this did nothing at all.  I was in a rush and didn't have time to look into the figures/tables.  I think you want `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` in your preamble for those things.  See [this answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/78866) for more details.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear why the page numbering is resetting... the page numbers should be continuous regardless.  I didn't notice anything in your example the forces them to reset (although, the layout doesn't seem to print page numbers anyway).  Also, you are including all your chapters from external files, which makes this not minimal working example.  I would suggest cutting out much of your preamble and just have a few `\chapter`s, `\sections`s, `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`s, and `\begin{table}...\end{table}`s.

Comment: A clarification.  `\@removefromreset` can be used so that (for example) sections within each chapter are continuous.  For  example, normally you have Chapter 1, Section 1.1, Section 1.2, Chapter 2, Section 2.1, etc.  But using this will give you Chapter 1, Section 1.1, Section 1.2, Chapter 2, Section 2.3, etc. (i.e. the section numbers never reset).  On my first read through, I mistakenly thought you wanted *everything* with continuous numbering.

Comment: One more follow up, which I forgot about.  Actually `\@removefromreset` can be used instead of the `chngcntr` package.  For example, `\@removefromreset{figure}{chapter}` and `\@removefromreset{figure}{section}`.  If you also need to remove the chapter number from each figure and table number, you can use `\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}`  A similar approach can be used for tables (i.e. replace `figure` with `table`) in the examples above.

Comment: Seems the package \usepackage{chappg} is actually causing this! Removing the package reverts to continuous page numbering. I'll try the other options to tweak graphics and table numbering.

Comment: I see, I didn't check all the packages closely.  According to `chappg` documentation, it is a  LaTeX package for numbering pages “by chapter”.  Looks like that is really it's only purpose.  Interesting to note that it also uses `\@addtoreset` and `\@removefromreset` in its implementation.