# How to change numbering of listings

Tags: numbering, listings

My listings have the numbering 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 - 2.1, 2.2, ... I need them to be continuous regardless of the chapter or section, being 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

The commands i used on listings:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Trecho de código}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Lista de trechos de código}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. A rather thorough answer to this type of question can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/, but Jake's answer there also answers your specific question I believe, in the final paragraph: *"To turn off the environment's per-chapter numbering for classes that feature `\chapter`, issue `\lstset{numberbychapter=false}` in the document preamble."*

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Would you like to add an answer or should we close the question as duplicate?

Comment: Close with duplicate please, thanks