# How to make section numbers be in order?

Tags: sectioning

Apologies for wording my question strangely, but here's what I am asking. So I have the following commands:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{corollary}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\theoremstyle{lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
```

When I do say three definitions they come up as Definition 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 which is great, but when I do say a lemma after them it says Lemma 1.1, how do I change it so that it says Lemma 1.4?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining theorem environments with `amsthm`, you can group counters with an optional argument of the `\newtheorem` command. You can use the optional arguments of `\newtheorem` in two different ways:

```
\newtheorem{<environment name>}{<text>}[<parent counter>]
```

or

```
\newtheorem{<environment name>}[<shared counter>]{<text>}
```

The first option is the one you use in your example. The second option allows you to define a new theorem environment with a counter from another that you already defined. Then both environments will be numbered using the same counter. You can use the same counter for more than two environments if you want.

Here's a small example to show how it works. For more details, see the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) of `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}[definition]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{definition}
First definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Other definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
First lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{thm}
First theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :)