# Memoir: create a subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, memoir

Given following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\part{PART}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SUBSECTION}
\subsubsection{SUBSUBSECTION}
\end{document}
```

I want no chapters. I want a  1 section, 1.1 subsection and a 1.1.2 subsubsection. And I don't want to use the documentclass article.

Comment: If you don't want chapters then why not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I have well understood your issue.

Is this what you are looking for?

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\part{PART}
\section{SECTION}
\subsection{SUBSECTION}
\subsubsection{SUBSUBSECTION}
\end{document}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Follow up question: how to make the caption follow this new circumstances?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: My first figure is 0.1 and not [section number].1

Comment: Would this help ?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Comment: '\counterwithin{figure}{section}' does the trick, thank you