# LaTex amsmath package. I want the equation counter to continue throughout the whole document

Tags: equations, amsmath

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
```

I want the equation numbering to increase throughout the entire document, not reset in every chapter. I have the format I want for the equation numbering (1) (2) etc, but it resets when I start a new chapter.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Remove `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}` and add `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` to your preamble instead. See also: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/134144)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a new enough latex

```
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so close to this solution but couldn't get it right. Thanks for the quick response!