# How to number the sections consecutively

Tags: numbering

I use scrbook and want to number the sections consecutively,
so i don't want to make them dependent on the chapter.
Instead of 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, ... it should be 1, 2, 3, 4, .... .

Thanks for your help, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `\counterwithout` [as shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/82917). However, since the April 2018 release the functionality of the `chngcntr` package has been integrated directly into the LaTeX kernel, so you can just use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% \usepackage{chngcntr} % not necessary in recent distributions
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\chapter{Second}
\section{Baz}
\section{Bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am so grateful, thank you so much!